# how to arrange output dfs on a single worksheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 data frames  I want all thee df output on one worksheet  1st df  should start from C2 cell,  2ND df should start from H2 cell, 3rd df should start from C8 cell.
Image of [output df arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhfs2.jpg) is attached.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mode = 'a' which means append mode?
ex. open the file in 'a', use to_csv() to write the first dataframe. Repeat for the other dataframes.

Or pass mode = 'a' to to_csv when you writing to the csv file.

Comment: Than you linlin for replying . but i am new to python. can you please wright an eg code.